# "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" in bootstrap-table plugin

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I'm using [bootstrap-table plugin](https://bootstrap-table.com/) by wenzhixin. In these days I'm doing the migration of my web platform from bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 4 and some features of bootstrap table seems to be not working anymore. 
I was having trouble with onPostBody event: debugging my code using breakpoints in google chrome inspector I've found out that onPostBody event seems not to be fired at all. Therefore I've tried to attach onAll event to see which events are actually fired, and I've found out that only `pre-body.bs.table` event is fired, and after that I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Any help? Thank you.

I'm using bootstrap v4.3.1, bootstrap-table v1.14.2 and jquery v3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed by myself. The problem was about columns.

I was returning columns from my backend and one column had a wrong property which was causing the error